# What happens to ESP32 when VIN is connected, GND is not connected and an input pin is connected to the ground?

Tags: esp32

I have a box where we expose 3 pins, VIN, GND and an input pullup pin.
In the input pin I have a diode to avoid positive input.
In the ground is another diode to avoid positive input, too.

What happens to the ESP32 when VIN is connected, GND is not connected and an input pin is connected to the ground?

Comment: Without schematics we can only guess.

Comment: You should be able to tell us! I’d expect the ESP32 to start working. As to how long it would work for in this out of spec condition it’s anyone’s guess. Needless to say, this is a situation you want to avoid.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Image stolen from [there](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/343979/esd-protection-diode-circuit-confusion). Pretty much every chip must be protected against ESD in order to survive. A usual way to do this is having internal ESD protection diodes on pins to prevent excessive positive or negative voltage from damaging the chip. It's not the only way: if a 3V3 micro has 5V tolerant inputs, the top diode will be replaced with something else. The lower diode will be present unless the input tolerates negative voltages lower than one diode drop below the negative supply, which is pretty rare. So for a micro, you can count on the lower ESD diode being there.

If VCC is present, ground is disconnected, and an input is grounded, current will flow from VCC, through the chip (powering it), trough the chip's internal ground, through the lower ESD diode, and out the GPIO pin, to the ground it is connected to.

Thus the chip will be powered and start up. If it draws more current than what the diode can tolerate, it'll burn and the chip will probably be toast. Otherwise, it'll just work. ESP32 can use quite a lot of current so it'll probably die.

However this is not all! ESP32 is connected to a SPI flash, which shares the same VCC and GND, and all the current used by this (and the whole board) will go through that ESD diode...